# ConnectionTimeout is not working as expected in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
      HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
      httpClient.connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 180);
      HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(params)));
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 180));
      httpClient.close();

      String chargeSessionEndPoint;
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //Handling Response
      }
```

There is a delay (around 3 minutes) in getting response from my server. Since I put Timeout for 3mins but still it's timing out for 1minute.

Could you help me out please?

Used http package.

Comment: Why there is 3 minutes of delay? It's unconvinient to have such delays in HTTP request. You may need to use other solutions like sockets or push notifications if the server needs more time.